# Is Carlos Simpson's Descent available online?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, descent

I am not sure whether this question is suitable for MO. Is the paper "Descent" by Carlos Simpson in the book "Alexandre Grothendieck: A Mathematical Portrait" page 83-142 (or a similar version of that paper) available anywhere online?

Comment: Here is a link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0ft4tiop740wjv/SIMPSON%20Descent.pdf?dl=0 (I don't remember where I found this.)

Comment: @AdeelKhan Thank you! That's exactly what I want. It's a pity that I cannot accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: It seems that it is no longer on that site.  Look at the n-Lab page on Carlos for a summary.